# Can we build a typescript type based on the shape of a prop?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a list of types:

```
type A = 1
type B = 2
type X = 'x'
type Y = 'y'
```

I'm going to receive an object like: `Record<string, A | B>`. For instance: `{ test1: A, test2: B, test3: A}`. I would like to create a function that would return me this type: `{ test1: X, test2: Y, test3: X }`

I know that we can do: `type Result<T> = T extends A ? X: T extends B ? Y : never` to map `A` to `x` and `B` to `Y`, but here is the best I could do:

```js
function transform <U extends string> (p: Record<U, A | B>): Record<U, Result<A | B>> {
  const result = {} as Record<U, Result<A | B>>
  (Object.keys(p) as U[]).forEach(k => (result[k] = p[k] === 1 ? 'x' as const : 'y' as const))
  return result
}

const a = transform({ test1: 1 as const, test2: 2 })
// a: Record<"test2" | "test1", "x" | "y">
// So a.test1 is of type 'x' | 'y' and not 'x'
```

I'm actually not sure that what I'm trying to achieve is doable with typescript when you don't know the exact shape of the input...

### Examples:

| input type | result type |
| --- | --- |
| { foo: A; bar: B } | { foo: X; bar: Y } |
| { test1: A; test2: B; test3: A } | { test1: X; test2: Y; test3: X } |
| { test1: A; test2: A; test3: A } | { test1: X; test2: X; test3: X } |
| { stuff: A } | { stuff: X } |

Basically, knowing that `A type` will be mapped to ̀X type`, and` B type`will be mapped to`Y type`, I want that my` transform` function returns me an object where I can ensure that:

- a key not present in `input` is not present in `output`, and so `output[key]` should raise an error
- if `input[key]` was of type A, `output[key]` is correctly inferred to the type `X`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Could you please provide more examples of what you are trying to achieve with some expected and unexpected behavior?

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's achievable with [conditinal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). Here is a possible solution with a helper type `MapResult`.

```
type MapResult<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]:
        T[K] extends A ? X
        : T[K] extends B ? Y
        : unknown
}

function transform <U extends Record<string, A | B>>(p: U): MapResult<U> {
    const result: Record<string, X | Y> = {};
    Object.keys(p).forEach(k =>
        result[k] = p[k] === 1 ? 'x' : 'y'
    )
    return result as MapResult<U>;
}
```

This should meet your requirements. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UCMBYAUKSUBCCoCZ1NoANPAcgA9yjxoBNCkGtWrAWQEMwAlCAZwCuAG2AAeACoA+PAG90URVADaAaSgBLAHZQA1hBAB7AGZQJAXQBcCpbYlrzUCJWAQtAE36woAfigkbW0VLMwcnFzdPHF8oekCgkMEtXS1DAHctdABfdHRjJIBjYA1DHWAAJ04tfmNDcoBbKDEAVXDXDy8+Arr3MX4K7QBzABpvAB8cKSkACjAQ5oBKEK5eARFxZpl5NFtu6uAocrXREK6evoGtEf8oCfoZRFksgG54gHkAIwArCCKAOn0IH4swWf1q5QAopwCgALaa6BBSeK2I5CUTKXSORBgDFY+CIJAxKjkKAhcjMeILeJHYCCco6VHrKCcLwrPhojZSV5oHJoIA)

Comment: I'm impressed! I really thought that it would not have been possible. Thanks a lot, you're a genius! :)